# Neo4j unmanaged extension - add custom request Filter to web server

Tags: java, neo4j

We have unmanaged extension. We implemented custom communication API between server and client.

Now we need to ensure that client and server have same API version.

One solution - verify version in each resource. But this approach is messy and leads to code duplication.

What we want is to implement our own [Filter](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html) and add it to Neo server.

Is this possible? If yes - then how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is possible!

Approach is a bit tricky and fragile, but it's working ([blog post](http://vrublevsky.me/neo4j/java/how-to-add-filter-in-neo4j-unmanaged-extension.html)).

#### Dependency

You need `neo4j-server` dependency, because it contains `SPIPluginLifecycle` that is needed to get access to Neo4j web server.

So, add to your `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.neo4j.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>neo4j-server</artifactId>
  <version>${version.neo4j}</version>
</dependency>
```

#### Filter

Create your filter. Let's take this one for example:

```
public class CustomFilter implements Filter {

    public CustomFilter() {
    }

    @Override
    public void init(final FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {}

    @Override
    public void doFilter(final ServletRequest request,
                         final ServletResponse response,
                         final FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {}
}
```

This filter doesn't do anything usefull - just continue chain further.

#### Lifecycle plugin

Now tricky part. We need to:

- Implement `SPIPluginLifecycle`
- Get web server
- Add filter to web server

Code:

```
public final class ExtensionPluginLifecycle implements SPIPluginLifecycle {

    private WebServer webServer;
    private CustomFilter customFilter;

    @Override
    public Collection<Injectable<?>> start(final NeoServer neoServer) {
        webServer = getWebServer(neoServer);

        addFilters();
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        removeFilters();
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<Injectable<?>> start(final GraphDatabaseService graphDatabaseService,
                                         final Configuration config) {
        throw new IllegalAccessError();
    }

    private WebServer getWebServer(final NeoServer neoServer) {
      if (neoServer instanceof AbstractNeoServer) {
          return ((AbstractNeoServer) neoServer).getWebServer();
      }
      throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("Expected: [AbstractNeoServer], Received: [%s].", neoServer));
    }

    private void addFilters() {
        customFilter = new CustomFilter();
        webServer.addFilter(customFilter, "/extension-path/*");
    }

    private void removeFilters() {
        webServer.removeFilter(customFilter, "/extension-path/*");
    }
}
```

Tricky part is not so "legal" access to web server. This can break in future, so be carefull.

Note `addFilters()` and `removeFilters()` methods - this is why we have been done all this way.

**Important:** lifecycle plugin should be registered as service:

```
// file: META-INF/services/org.neo4j.server.plugins.PluginLifecycle
my.company.extension.ExtensionPluginLifecycle
```